# Powershell script searching files on domain

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a simple PowerShell script that will run on an admin VM I have setup on my domain. I have a separate SQL VM running a backup script that consume a lot of storage over time. I am trying to run this very simple script.

Do I need to modify this script in order to store it on my admin VM, but have it run on my SQL VM? Or can I leave the path as is and just set up in AD task scheduler?

I have tried targeting the FQDN and the IP, but it doesn't seem to work either way.

```
$backups_file = 'E:\blahBlahBla\SQL\Backups'  or
$backups_file = '<IP_ADDRESS>\E:\blahBlahBla\SQL\Backups'  or
$backups_file = '<FQDN>E:\blahBlahBla\SQL\Backups'  

$backup_file_exist = (Test-Path -Path $backups_file)

if ($backup_file_exist){

    # Verifies the folder exists
    Write-Output -InputObject "This folder exists" 
    # returns all the files in the folder. 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $backups_file 
    # Deletes all files in the folder that are older that 7 days.
    Get-ChildItem -Path $backups_file -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get- 
    Date).AddDays(-7))} | Remove-Item 

}
else
{
    Write-Output -InputObject "Unable to access this directory."
}
```

Comment: can you navigate to those path in file explorer from your admin vm? i don't see why these wouldn't work otherwise. what error are you getting back?:

Comment: I am beginning to think this is a network configuration issue. I tried to schedule a task from the sql vm and could not map the network drive over to the admin vm where the script is stored.

Answer (score 0):

All your `$backups_file` solutions seems wrong to me.
If you want excess a directory on a Remote system, it has to be at least a fileshare or a administrative share like `\\\\computer\e$\folder\folder\`

But why using file shares or something like that when you just simple can connect to a PowerShell Session on the Remote Host? here is a example:

```
$mySQLServer = "Server1.domain.name", "server2.domain.name"
$backupFolder = "E:\blahBlahBla\SQL\Backups"
foreach ($server in $mySQLServer)
{
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server #maybe -cred if needed
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $backupFolder -ScriptBlock {
        param(
            $directoy
        )
        if ($backup_file_exist)
        {
            # Verifies the folder exists
            Write-Output -InputObject "This folder exists"
            # returns all the files in the folder.
            Get-ChildItem -Path $directoy
            # Deletes all files in the folder that are older that 7 days.
            Get-ChildItem -Path $directoy -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))
            } | Remove-Item
        }
    }
    Remove-PSSession
}
```